# How do I make the 'me' element only show the first time you load the home page with javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
< script >
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById('me').classList.add('fade');
  }, 1700); <
/script>
```

This is the code I made so the picture fades out right when the visitor is on the home page. Is there javascript code to add so that it only shows once? I don't want it to show again if they use a link and then come back.

Comment: please add proper code. this is not right way to do. add script part in script block of editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/MoloF/8hc1x7ne/17/)**, allowed only on jsFiddle

```js
(function(){
 const reset = document.querySelector('.reset');
 const update = document.querySelector('.update');
 const status = document.querySelector('p b');
 const image = document.querySelector('img');
 const isLoaded = !!localStorage.getItem('already-loaded');

 if (!isLoaded) localStorage.setItem('already-loaded', true);

 reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
  localStorage.removeItem('already-loaded');
  location.reload();
 });

 update.addEventListener('click', () => location.reload());
 
 status.innerHTML = isLoaded ? 'already loaded' : 'first time here';
 image.style.display = isLoaded ? 'none' : 'block';
})//() this does not work on stackoverflow
```

```html
<button class="reset">reset</button>
<button class="update">update</button>

<p>Status: <b></b></p>
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/400/500/300.jpg" alt="">
```